# Sort values by numerical range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sorting some values specifying the concrete node with pandas,

```
node='tds210'

filtered_node=result[result.my_remote_host.str.contains(node,case=False,na=False)]
```

How can I sort the whole values in the range tds200 to tds300 in a single dataframe?

Comment: Using `sort_values()`?

Comment: Not actually, values are strings finishing with a certain range of numbers between 200 and 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a random integer to the test string to make sure the code works even if you have any other characters (letters or numbers) besides the `tdsXXX` string. The [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)  portion of the code is using a regular expression with word boundaries between the `tdsXXX` pattern. To verify that the numbers are, in fact, between 200 and 300 the capturing group `(2\d\d|300)` was used. After the extraction, if you only need those entries between 200 and 300 use `dropna()` to remove any entries that don't match the required range. The remaining values are then sorted and the resulting `index` from that sort is used over the original dataframe (`result`).

*result* dataframe used as input

```
              my_remote_host
0   this 26 is a tds136 test
1   this 68 is a tds132 test
2   this 16 is a tds215 test
3   this 31 is a tds382 test
4   this 18 is a tds259 test
5  this 100 is a tds247 test
6   this 13 is a tds137 test
7   this 40 is a tds343 test
8   this 63 is a tds170 test
9   this 50 is a tds205 test
```

```
import pandas as pd
import re

regex = r"\btds(2\d\d|300)\b"

# filter by TDS value
filtered_node = result.my_remote_host.str.extract \
        (pat = regex, flags = re.I).dropna()
# sort by TDS value
sorted_tds = filtered_node.sort_values([0])
# use sorted index over result dataFrame
sorted_res = result.iloc[sorted_tds.index]
print(sorted_res)
```

Output from *sorted_res*

```
              my_remote_host
9   this 50 is a tds205 test
2   this 16 is a tds215 test
5  this 100 is a tds247 test
4   this 18 is a tds259 test
```